# Formatting multi line equations in latex

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to format a multi-line equation like shown below

[image]

But it is appearing like this

[image]

Code

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:eq1}
    a_1 = b_1 + c_1 \\
    d_1 = a_1
\end{equation}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I format it properly as shown in picture 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
\begin{align}
    \label{eq:eq1}
    a_1 &= b_1 + c_1 \\
    d_1 &= a_1
\end{align}
```